# invalid_credentials with omniauth on heroku

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth-provider

I implemented a project configured with OmniAuth/Twitter and OmniAuth/Facebook. in development mode with any problem.

But when i tried on heroku. it refused to work.

```
 use Rack::Session::Cookie
  use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_APP_ID'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
    provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], :scope => 'email'
  end
```

Heroku logs

```
012-11-02T03:28:47+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2012-11-02T03:28:47.339453 #58] ERROR -- omniauth: (twitter) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth::Unauthorized, 401 Unauthorized
2012-11-02T03:28:47+00:00 heroku[router]: GET p####.herokuapp.com/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=r6l3GpwmxH38W8Q9WltcWs9PqyyGxxiGAUqXGFhmKs&oauth_verifier=O9HD6jLaEL1aRUcORIebGEZIQHbqtcgB012q5aZlCE dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=368ms status=302 bytes=9
2012-11-02T03:28:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 92.160.179.137 - - [02/Nov/2012 03:28:47] "GET /auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&origin=https%3A%2F%2F p####.herokuapp.com%2Flogin&strategy=twitter HTTP/1.1" 200 3160 0.0033
2012-11-02T03:28:47+00:00 heroku[router]: GET  p####.herokuapp.com/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&origin=https%3A%2F%2F p####.herokuapp.com%2Flogin&strategy=twitter dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=3160
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you defined TWITTER_APP_ID, TWITTER_SECRET, .. environment variables ?

Comment: Yes. I have added my var configs local side and heroku side.

Answer (score 3):

A few things. Run `$ heroku config` and make sure the right keys are on Heroku.

Also, not sure about Twitter, but Facebook requires a callback url that you put in the settings for your app on developer.facebook.com, and that needs to point to the heroku url or it will be invalid.

Another long shot, but it could be an issue with CA certificates. I had that problem and fixed it with this in an initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], { 
    client_options: { ssl: { 
        ca_file: '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt',
        ca_path: "/etc/ssl/certs"
    }}
  }
end
```

Hope this helps some..

Comment: The SSL fix worked for me (different provider, not facebook). You saved me hours, sir.